# devEMF package in R 3.5 on macOS doesn't build

Tags: r, package, homebrew

I'm trying to install and build from source the package `devEMF` but it doesn't build. I've tried to install on macOS 10.11.6 and 10.13.4 with the same exact result. In both system I have a R install with Homebrew.

Any idea about what could be the problem?

Thanks!

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/lpuerto/Library/R/3.x/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devEMF_3.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 201425 bytes (196 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 196 KB

* installing *source* package ‘devEMF’ ...
** package ‘devEMF’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++  -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.0/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include   -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe -c devEMF.cpp -o devEMF.o
In file included from devEMF.cpp:45:
./fontmetrics.h:470:19: error: no matching function for call to 'CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs'
        extents = CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(m_FontInfo, 0, &glyph,
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CTFont.h:875:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'CTFontOrientation' for 2nd argument
CGRect CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(
       ^
In file included from devEMF.cpp:45:
./fontmetrics.h:474:17: error: no matching function for call to 'CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs'
        width = CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs(m_FontInfo, 0, &glyph, NULL, 1);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CTFont.h:933:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'CTFontOrientation' for 2nd argument
double CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs(
       ^
In file included from devEMF.cpp:45:
./fontmetrics.h:486:20: error: no matching function for call to 'CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs'
        double w = CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs(m_FontInfo, 0, glyphs, NULL,
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CTFont.h:933:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'CTFontOrientation' for 2nd argument
double CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs(
       ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [devEMF.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘devEMF’
* removing ‘/Users/lpuerto/Library/R/3.x/library/devEMF’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devEMF’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/wf/41gjf2mx7m7fmvfd8dr22_5h0000gn/T/RtmpvEhMHs/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: I realize this may not help too much but FWIW macOS 10.13.5 Beta (17F45c), AT&T R 3.5 binaries, clang++ == install from source worked fine. Homebrew R is great and all, but it might be worth trying the official R installation as well and report back if that fixed it, since that, then, means the issue is very likely Homebrew R-related.

Comment: You helped me a lot because you make me realize that perhaps the makevars were involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent change in some combination of clang / OSX CoreText API / R exposed a bug in the devEMF package, whereby it relied on an "int" data type being automatically cast to an "enum" data type.

devEMF version 3.6-1 fixes this bug by directly using the appropriate enum constant.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I figured it out! Seems that the problem was the makevars.

This is my makevars file

```
# Remove the comment on -fopenmp for compiling data.table package
CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang #-fopenmp
CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ #-fopenmp
# -O3 should be faster than -O2 (default) level optimisation ..
CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include
```

I commented all lines and installed it perfectly. Perhaps it isn't compatible with LLVM. I don't know.

Comment: Definitely make sure to accept your answer when whatever the current time limit for that is up. You did a great deal of  debugging for this.